# Get Tile Location On Screen (Java Slick and Tiled2D)

Tags: java, tiles, slick

I want to create a rectangle around each tile that's blocked value = true. How can I find the X and Y (on screen) coords of the each individual Tile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate each tile position on screen if you know the width and height of each tile like this:

```
pos.x = x * tileWidth;
pos.y = y * tileHeight;
```

Therefore, you can go through all the tiles:

```
for(x = 0; x < tilemap.getWidth(); x++)
for(y = 0; y < tilemap.getHeight(); y++)
{
    if(tilemap.tiles[x][y].blocked == true){
        // This tile is blocked, get it's position on screen
        pos.x = x * tileWidth;
        pos.y = y * tileHeight;
    }
}
```